# How to fix Redirect Loop error?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a user login site, I have a header.php and a home.php documents.
I have the following code on the header.php page:

```
<?php 
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php"); 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
}
else 
{
header("location: home.php");

}
?>
```

on the home.php page i have:

```
<?php
include("inc/header.inc.php");
?>
<?
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])

?>
```

No matter what i try I am getting this loop error, please help :(

Comment: Are you missing `session_start` in home.php? Where is the redirect in home.php?

Comment: Well, if `$_SESSION['user_login']` is not set, then you have an endless loop: `header.php` is included at the top of `home.php`, thus executed first and _always_ redirects again to `home.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `exit();` after `header("location: ..");` or it might not work as expected.

About Loop Error its possible both `header.php` and `home.php` are redirecting to each other.

I am not sure if its the same file (correct me if am wrong)

In `header.php` you are redirecting user to `home.php` if session is not set AND in `home.php` you are including a file `header.inc.php`(i am assuming its the same file) which is redirecting user to `home.php` again and again

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that sets `$_SESSION['user_login']` in those two files, you need to set this parameter in `header.php` otherwise it will keep falling into this condition:

```
else 
{
header("location: home.php");
}
```

The loop is as follows:

1. User comes to `home.php`
2. `header.php` is included
3. `header.php` checks to see if `$_SESSION['user_login']` has been set
4. It hasn't so the header location is set to `home.php`
5. Go to step 1

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve here, but I'm going to assuming you want to display a page, but if the user isn't logged in to display something else?

Why not:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']) {
    include('logged_in.php');
} else {
    include('login_page.php');
}
```

Rather than bounce the user around, just display a different file?